# Angular ngClass background color change with condition

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I use this part of code to change the background color of a cell when register.day is equals to 'NO REG.':

```
<td class="text-center" [ngClass]="{'red': register.day1 == 'NO REG.'}"> {{register.day1}} </td>
```

Is there is any way to use ngClass and change the background color of a cell,  when the register.day1 equals to '(any hour) - NO REG.' or 'NO REG. - 2:30' for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean OR

```
[ngClass]="{'red': register.day1 == 'NO REG.'|| register.day1 == 'NO REG. - 2:30'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ngclass on the 
NO REG. - 2:30 condition match and for other set a different background like this below

```
<td class="text-center" [ngClass]="{'color': register.day1 == 'NO REG. - 2:30' , 'color2' :register.day1 != 'NO REG. - 2:30'  }"> {{register.day1}} </td>
```